# Обмен ассоциациями между записями ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Здравствуйте, товарищи!

Итак, имеем:

```
class Dice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sign_a, class_name: 'Sign'
  belongs_to :sign_b, class_name: 'Sign'
  belongs_to :sign_c, class_name: 'Sign'
  ...
  belongs_to :dice_place, polymorphic: true

  validates :sign_a, :sign_b, :sign_c, ..., :dice_place, presence: true
end

class BagDicePlace < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :dice, as: :dice_place, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Допустим, мы как-то получили записи `bag_dice_place_1` и `bag_dice_place_2` и у каждой из них ассоциация `dice` со всеми вложенными ассоциациями уже загружены.

Как поменять местами эти `dice`-ы, сгенерировав минимальное количество запросов к базе?

Теоретически, все должно уложиться в 2 апдейта в 1-й транзакции. А вот как это сделать - не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу сам.

```
d1 = bag_dice_place_1.dice
d2 = bag_dice_place_2.dice

Dice.transaction do
  if d1
    d1.update(dice_place: bag_dice_place_2)
  end

  if d2
    d2.update(dice_place: bag_dice_place_1)
  end
end

bag_dice_place_1.association(:dice).target = d2
bag_dice_place_2.association(:dice).target = d1
```